# Returning a collection of objects from API endpoint to Angular results in error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET Web Api endpoint that returns a List of Contacts.

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerId {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

I obtain the `List<Customer>` as such within the API endpoint. Setting a breakpoint I can verify the collection contains `Customer` objects.

```
List<Customer> myResults = GetCustomers();
```

I am attempting to return the collection of Contacts from the API using ...

```
return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Customer>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, myResults);
```

I have Angular code that I am hoping to use to parse the returned data.

```
.then(function (data) {
    // promise fulfilled
    $scope.uploading = false;
    if (data.length === 0) {
        alert("No data returned");
    } else {
        $scope.results = data;
    }
}, function (error) {
    //Server Error
    alert("Function error " + error);
}
```

However the result is always an error and I am not sure why.

[image]

Am I not returning the collection of Customers properly?